# ASP.NET Core Model Binding - InvalidOperationException when defining different @model's in _Layout and View

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I get an InvalidOperationException when defining different @model's for _Layout and a different view.

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'ConsumeWebAPI_Basic.ViewModels.ApiResponse', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'ConsumeWebAPI_Basic.ViewModels.MovieSearch'.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@model ConsumeWebAPI_Basic.ViewModels.MovieSearch
```

**Response.cshtml**

```
@model ConsumeWebAPI_Basic.ViewModels.ApiResponse
```

Answer (score 2):

So remove model from `_Layout.cshtml` or use different layout with the same model cuz .Net cant convert byself `MovieSearch` to `ApiResponse`. The model between layout and view is shared

At least you can use dynamic model in layout but i can't recommend this

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Partial View and passes the model through @Html.Partial

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu", new ConsumeWebAPI_Basic.ViewModels.MovieSearch(), new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData))
```